# What is bitwise OR used here for?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

```
descriptor  =  limit       & 0x000F0000;        
descriptor |= (flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00;        
descriptor |= (base >> 16) & 0x000000FF;        
descriptor |=  base        & 0xFF000000;
```

I understood the fact that the and operation is used for masking certain bits. But what is OR operation used here for??? Please elaborate.
This is part of the code for creating a Global Descriptor Table.

Comment: The OR operation here is used to OR things together, as always. That's really tautological. I'm not sure whether there's a real question here to answer.

Comment: What's being done is the creation of a mask or bit-pattern named descriptor.

Comment: By the way, since the masks are disjoint, they could equivalently have used `+=` or `^=`, though that would be pointless and less obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the code you've shown is doing is constructing `descriptor` by selecting different parts of it from other boolean expressions.

Notice that the constants that `(flag << 8)`, `(base >> 16)` and `base` are being ANDed with, when themselves ORed together, produce `0xFFFFFFFF`.

The point of the OR is to say, "the first 8 bits come from `(base >> 16)`, the next 8 bits from `flag << 8`, the next 4 from `limit`, the next 4 from `flag << 8` and the last 8 from `base`." So finally, descriptor looks like this:

```
d[7], d[6], b[5], a[4], b[3], b[2], c[1], c[0]
```

Where each comma separated variable is a hexadecimal digit, and `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are
`limit`, `(flag << 8)`, `(base >> 16)` and `base` respectively. (The commas are just there for readability, they stand for concatenation of the digits).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at just a single bit, the truth table is given by

```
0 | 0 == 0
0 | 1 == 1
1 | 0 == 1
1 | 1 == 1
```

So, bitwise or sets a bit if and only if that bit is set in at least one of the operands.

---

When you use bitwise or on a variable with more that a single bit, the above truth table is applied in a bitwise fashion.

So, suppose that you had two variables whose binary representations were

```
001101
011001
```

When you combine them with bitwise or, you collect all the bits that are set in **either** variable. So the result is

```
011101
```

---

The bitwise or operator is commonly used to add new flags to a set of bit flags. The value is used to represent a mathematical set. Each bit is assigned a particular meaning, that is associated with a member of the universal set. When the bit is 1, that member is included in the set, and when the bit is 0, the associated member is not in the set.

So, let us have a very simple example with a universal set having two members. Let us call the variable, `controlState`. Bit 0 represents the visible property, and bit 1 represents the enabled property. So, you can define flags like so

```
const int visibleFlag = 1; // 01 in binary
const int enabledFlag = 2; // 10 in binary
```

Then you can build the `controlState` variable like this:

```
int controlState = 0; // empty set
if (isVisible) 
    controlState |= visibleFlag;
if (isEnabled)
    controlState |= enabledFlag;
```

It gets more interesting if you don't know whether or not a particular bit is set. So, you can ensure that the visible bit is set like this:

```
controlState = ...; // could set visible flag, or not ...
controlState |= visibleFlag;
```

It does not matter whether the original value of `controlState` included the flag or not. After this operation, it will be set for sure, and no other flags altered.

---

This is what is happening in your code example. So,

```
descriptor  =  limit       & 0x000F0000;
```

initializes `descriptor`. Then

```
descriptor |= (flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00;
```

adds `(flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00`. And so on.

Comment: ok, the bits that are set in both are collected, but why?, what's the use?

Comment: I've tried to expand on this in the updated answer because I think that you are perhaps missing the connection between bitwise or and bit flag sets. Although, given the answer that you just accepted, I suspect that I've completely mis-judged what you were struggling with. Hey ho!

Comment: even if this was not what I was looking for, I still got some useful info. Thanks.

Comment: What were you looking for? Did you already know about bitsets? Your first comment suggested that you did not.

Comment: @memnonila; I still did't understand what you wanted to know?

Comment: No I did not know about bitsets. And I was trying to understand what happens to the descriptor.

Comment: @haccks What asQuirreL said is what I wanted to know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But I understood what happens in this code from that answer.

Comment: It's fine. I was just trying to understand exactly where you were coming from. I'm pleased that my reading of your comment was accurate.

Comment: I mean that I read your original comment to mean that you did not know about bitsets.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `|=` here is essentially short hand for the following

```
descriptor = destriptor | ((flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00);
```

Comment: @memnonila the `|` operator will return a value where if the bit was set on the left or the right it will be set in the final value

Answer (score 0):

Bit-wise OR `|` operator (copies a bit if it exists in either operand) used here to ORing the `descriptor` with right hand operator of `=` and store the result to `descriptor`. It is equivalent to

```
descriptor = descriptor | (flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00;
```

Truth table fo OR operation:

[image]

For `x = 1 1 0 0` and `Y = 1 0 1 0` OR operation works as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`descriptor` is a collection of values packed together as bitfields. This code is building it up from four values (`limit`, `flag`, and two parts of `base`). Each step is shifting the value to the correction bit position and then ANDing with a mask to ensure the bits don't spill over into other positions. The `A |= B` operator expands to `A = A | B` and merges together all of the individual results. This could also be done using a `struct` with bitfields, although perhaps with less portability.